# Add condition to LINQ LET query?

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to be able to add an if statement into a linq query to add a second LET.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  Thanks

```
var query = from d in myList
group d by d.Date
into v
let dataSum = nv.Sum(x => x.Data)
select new MyObject(){ Date = nv.Key.Date, Data = dataSum}

//Invalid I know... but something like this is what I'm looking for
var query = from d in myList
group d by d.Date
into v
let dataSum = nv.Sum(x => x.Data)
if(secondaryData){ let dataSum2 = nv.Sum(x.Data2)}
select new MyObject(){ Date = nv.Key.Date, Data = dataSum}
```

Comment: That's not how LINQ is supposed to be used.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SLaks I'm trying to make the query generic enough to be able to be used in a condition where I need to have 2 columns summed.  I could write two queries but they would be almost identical.

Comment: @NullReference, a question starting from invalid syntax is unlikely to yield useful results (and useful as a reference, not just your very specific issue). I recommend that you start from what you are actually trying to accomplish instead.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon I added the "invalid syntax" as a sample of that I'm looking for... I'll add that as a note in the question.

Comment: @NullReference yes, but that doesn't make it a good question. Amiram has an answer that gives you a possible syntax, but it's impossible to know if that's what you really need.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the if shorthand:

```
let dataSum2 = secondaryData ? nv.Sum(x.Data2) : 0
```

Comment: Ternary operator, for future reference. =)

Comment: @J.Steen - Actually it is a Conditional operator. A Ternary operator is an operator that takes 3 arguments

Comment: Well, it's common enough to call it the ternary operator that both are accepted. Even if Microsoft do name it the conditional operator, yes. Then again, all knowing Wikipedia names it the ternary operator. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
List<Product1> prods = new List<Product1>();
        prods.Add(new Product1() { ProductPrice = 1, ValidFrom = DateTime.Today });
        prods.Add(new Product1() { ProductPrice = 3, ValidFrom = DateTime.Today });
        prods.Add(new Product1() { ProductPrice = 2, ValidFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) });
        prods.Add(new Product1() { ProductPrice = 5, ValidFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2) });
    // Put any logic you want in sumFunc. For any field you want like ProductPrice 
    Func<Product1, decimal> sumFunc = (p) => p.ProductPrice;

    var result = from c in prods
                 group c by c.ValidFrom into gd
                 let sum = gd.Sum(sumFunc)
                 select sum;
```